# How do implement step definition in multiple lines?

Tags: scala, cucumber, gherkin

I am using Scala, Cucumber, Gherkin language for automation test. I've the following scenario in my feature file, written in Gherkin language:

```
Scenario Outline: Do something
  When I do something  
  Then result should have field1 as "<filed_1>", field2 as "<filed_2>" and filed3 as "<filed_3>"
```

And the stepdef generated is:

```
When("""^I do something$""") {
        // do operation
}
Then("""^result should haveresult should have field1 as "([^"]*)", 
    field2 as "([^"]*)" and filed3 as "([^"]*)"$""") {
     // do operation
}
```

Here ***Then*** statement having more than 120 characters in a line which I have to break in two. I should not be changing feature file.

When break ***Then*** in two lines

```
Then("""^result should haveresult should have field1 as "([^"]*)", 
      | field2 as "([^"]*)" and filed3 as "([^"]*)"$""".stripMargin)
```

It saying You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
Then("""^result should have field1 as "([^"]*)", field2 as "([^"]*)" and filed3 as "([^"]*)"$"""){ (arg0:String, arg1:String, arg2:String) =>
  //// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  throw new PendingException()
}
```

I am not sure which approach should I be taking to break ***Then*** in multiple lines. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the `String` into two and add them together:

```
Then("""^result should have field1 as "(.*)", field2 as "(.*)" """ + 
  """and filed3 as "(.*)"$""") { (arg0:String, arg1:String, arg2:String) =>

  //etc
}
```

This is just the same as any `String` you want to split and then add up:

```
"""1234567890""" == """12345""" + """67890""" // true
```

Comment: Well, I tried that also, getting ***"You can implement missing steps"***

Comment: Gherkin/Cucumber tests run with basic Regex checks (hence `^`, `$`, `(.*)`, etc). It sounds like your StepDef doesn't match the Feature file. In your original question, you state that the `Then` block is `Then("""^result should haveresult should have field1 ...`. Is the duplicated `result should haveresult should have` a typo?

Comment: My bad. Updated the *Then* in question